# How to hide the backbutton in uinavigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, back-button, uinavigationitem

I tried to remove the backbutton of uinavigationcontroller by using

```
appdelegate.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
```

but it does not remove the backbutton after the pushing a new viewcontroller into navigation stack.How to hide this?

Comment: definitely you are hiding backbutton in current view. When push current view to next view, the new view should also hide the backbutton.

So, put the same line on next view also.

Comment: @Surjit Joshi i put the above line of code in the new view controllers viewdidload method ...but it is not disappearing

Comment: have you written “Back” in XIB of new/current view controller ??

If yes, remove it & then test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your above line is wrong. do it with  :

```
 self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 12):

In the view controller's viewDidLoad method that you want to hide the back button:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this in your `ViewDidLoad` as well as in `ViewWillAppear` method:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers didn't work for me. I found that the best way for me was:

> self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray array];